# fail: sending mail to facebook email adress with php mail() function

Tags: php, facebook, email, sendmail, spam

my mail system working well. hotmail, gmail or etc are not moving my server's sent mails to "spam" folder but there is something else : facebook mail.

I'm getting user's email when they are login to my website with facebook. After that I have to send email to their facebook.com email. I'm sendin but it's going into directly "Other messages" box. It's not shown on normal "Messages" box.

It's awful because there is no boarding for that new email user had received.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your emails are being flagged as spam in Facebook. No one really knows how Facebook will mark email as Spam but if you Google, there will be many ways you can avoid being detected as spam.

As I do with all my email, go through Postmark for my software, or SMTP.com for business mail. Sending it from your server, which I imagine is on a shared host, will alone almost always flag you as SPAM in many system.